# How to draw pure SVGs in Illustrator and avoid pixelation when exporting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

Pretty new to Illustrator, so I've been working on some graphics for quite a while and when I tried exporting it as SVG, to my surprise some parts of the artworks look blurry and pixelated.

I understand that SVG has limited features, but for some reason I though that Illustrator will convert my drawing to SVG-compatible under the hood, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

So, my question is: is there a mode in Adobe Illustrator where you can use only SVG-compatible tools and all others are blocked to avoid such surprises on the export stage? Or how people usually do this, just by learning which feature is compatible with SVG and which is not?

Comment: What kind of graphic are you talking about? How did you make it?  If you create a raster image (a pixel based image), place it in Illustrator, and export as SVG, it won't magically become vector. It will just be a raster image inside an SVG.  To create a vector image, you either need to recreate it by hand, or auto trace the image.

Comment: @BillyKerr I've created it from scratch. I've used mesh gradients, stroke gradients that, after some research, are not supported by SVG format. If I knew that before, I wouldn't have used them and used other options that are supported by svg. The whole point of using illustrator for me was to make scalable SVG. And turns out I just made pixel image just as I could in photoshop

Comment: Yeah, mesh gradients aren't supported in SVG, but SVG gradients are.

Comment: @BillyKerr so now I suppose that there are many more features that are not supported by SVG. Is there a way to know that beforehand or work in a UI limited to SVG?

Comment: Well, yes. Some things, such as Illustrator effects are not supported, but there are SVG effects that are.  If you are designing for SVG, best to keep it simple, pure vector, no effects. Simple gradients and SVG blurs should be OK though.

Comment: Here's [an example](https://svgshare.com/i/130Q.svg) avoiding things that aren't compatible with SVG. This was made in Inskscape, but the same is possible in Illustrator. You don't need mesh gradients. Instead, you can use blurs, gradients and clipping masks to get complex shading, etc.

Comment: [Another example here](https://svgshare.com/i/12xi.svg) I made some time ago

Comment: You can use an SVG-based program, like Inkscape. Its file format is SVG, so it doesn't have any tools or effects that can't be in an SVG graphic, as far as I know.

Comment: Id like to point out that gradient meshes were supposed to be in svg allready before adobe implemented them in illustrator. But browser vendors didnt want to implement gradient meshes so they are dead in water. But in general a good rule of thumb, before you do something test a minimal sample in application X. SVG isnt a simple all or nothing thing some stuff might work in some svg renderes but not others so be sure to test as you go.

Comment: @user8356 this isnt strictly speaking true. Additionally you cant assume all svg rendering tools support all the features inkscape supports. SVG is not one target

Comment: @user8356 - actually Inkscape has a few things which are not supported in SVG, such as mesh gradients (similar to Illustrator's). Also Live Path Effects would need to be turned into ordinary paths. Mesh gradients were supposed to be added to the SVG format, but apparently there were issues doing so. Perhaps it'll happen one day, but for the moment, it's unsupported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but for some reason I though that Illustrator will convert my drawing to SVG-compatible under the hood, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Nop. It is not. Not only with SVG but also with some versions of PDF, especially for print.

So the only thing you can do is make the base shape, a pure vector, closed paths, solid fills and strokes (RGB), and from there start adding specific things like gradients and testing them. Save incremental versions, like BunnyShapeSvg-01.ai so you can go back to a version that does not introduce rasterized elements.

Here is a list of features of the SVG.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element

I must say that even using Inkscape, which is SVG-based also produces raster elements. **You need to differentiate two concepts. Vector only and SVG compatible**. A raster element inside an SVG is SVG compatible, but not vector only.

A third thing to differentiate are effects that can be added after the SVG is generated, such as box-shadows.